# adminer- None of the supported PHP extensions (MySQLi, MySQL, PDO_MySQL) are available

Tags: apache2, php, database

whenever i login to the adminer, it always show:

```
    No Extension
             None of the supported PHP extensions (MySQLi, MySQL, PDO_MySQL) are available.
```

I just installed this a while ago using the source package and i put it on my DirectoryRoot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be the case that mysql is not configured with php. You can try and install it by the command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Refresh the browser. Hope it helps.

Comment: you will need to do a `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 14):

Now you need to make

`sudo apt-get install php-mysql`

Since on recent release you need to install the new php7 version

And finally `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the right package for the PHP version that it is running in the browser

To know your PHP version:

add `phpinfo();` function in any file for ex. `phpinfo.php`

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

open the file in the browser and check your PHP version

for me I have php8.0

so I run

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-mysql
```

and then restart apache by:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and now it is working fine

> if you have a different version for ex php8.1 replace the version
> after php => `php8.1-mysql` so it will be `sudo apt-get install php8.1-mysql`

[image: phpinfo.php]

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate your `php.ini` file.
2. Find the following extensions and remove their comments (i.e. remove the semi-colon):

   ```
   ;themextension=pdo_pgsql
   ;extension=pgsql
   ```
3. Restart your Apache server.