# None of the supported PHP extension for adminer even after linking php with mysql

Tags: mysql, php

After the installation of adminer and accessing from `localhost/adminer` it says

> None of the supported PHP extensions (MySQLi, MySQL, PDO_MySQL) are available

I even did the steps from [adminer- None of the supported PHP extensions (MySQLi, MySQL, PDO_MySQL) are available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599921/adminer-none-of-the-supported-php-extensions-mysqli-mysql-pdo-mysql-are-ava) but it didn't help out.

I am running `php version 7.1.10`. Any further configuration, do we  need to make it happen for ubuntu 17.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Adminer says

> None of the supported PHP extensions (MySQLi, MySQL, PDO_MySQL) are
>   available

it means exactly that your PHP interpreter has no support for this extensions.

There are several reasons why you don't have MySQL support in PHP, but the most common one is that you missed to install the right packages.

PHP packages related to MySQL can be searched with this command:

```
apt-cache search php | grep -i mysql
```

The most important are:

```
php-mysql - MySQL module for PHP [default]
php7.1-mysql - MySQL module for PHP
```

I'm using Kubuntu 17.10 with PHP 7.1, you may have a different version, but the most important and common package is **php-mysql**.

First of all you have to check in all your installed packages which "php" ones are installed on your machine:

```
dpkg -l | grep php
```

You must find at least one of the two php-mysql. If not you can install it using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

Now you just have to restart your services.

If your are using PHP with Apache with prefork, you just have to restart your webserver. If you are using FastCGI, you have to restart php service.

The right command depends on your Ubuntu version, you may use **systemctl** or **service** command:

```
sudo systemctl restart <servicename>
sudo service <servicename> restart
```

where **servicename** can be one of "apache", "apache2", "php5-fpm" or "php7.1-fpm".

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it says `php-mysql` and  `php7.0-mysql` are already installed.

Comment: So you may have some problems in php.ini configuration.
Just create a single php page called info.php in your document root and put inside this single row:
<? phpinfo(); >?
Open it in your browser anche check if MySQL extension is working.

Answer (score 3):

After updating my Debian system from Stretch to Buster, I have got the same error message on http://localhost/adminer/. The report page http://localhost/phpinfo.php, which essentially consists of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, revealed that PHP 7.0 is used by apache2 though the newer PHP 7.3 is already installed on the system. Activating the newer PHP version made to work Adminer again. I guess that this works on Ubuntu just the same.

```
$ a2dismod php7.0
$ a2enmod php7.3
$ systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the `phpinfo()` first which said that the MySQL PDO extension is not enabled, which was strange because I enabled it in the `php.ini` with `extension=pdo_mysql`. I checked the Apache `error.log` and it turned out that PHP was looking for the extension in the `c:\php\ext` directory while I had it in the `C:\PHP\php-7.4.24\ext` directory. So I changed the `php.ini` again `extension_dir = "C:/PHP/php-7.4.24/ext"` and problem solved.

I recommend the same steps to debug this issue, check if your exntesion of choice is really not enabled, which is likely. After that check the log files of your webserver, because it should write why it cannot enable the extension.